# Bootstrap-table add title to PDF export

Tags: jspdf, bootstrap-table, jspdf-autotable

I'm using the bootstrap-table plugin with the tableExport plugin (https://github.com/hhurz/tableExport.jquery.plugin).

I managed to export my table but I'd like to add a title in the PDF before the table itself. Here is my code:

```
$("#table").bootstrapTable({
    exportOptions: {
        fileName: 'export_anim',
        worksheetName: 'table',
        csvSeparator: ';',
        jspdf: {
            orientation: "l",
            autotable: {
                styles: {rowHeight: 14, fontSize: 8, fillColor: 240},
                headerStyles: {fillColor: 255, textColor: 0},
                alternateRowStyles: {fillColor: 210, textColor: 0}
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Is there any way I can do this ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to use the `beforePageContent` hook together with the `margin` option in autotable. Something like this:

```
autotable: {
    margin: {top: 80},
    beforePageContent: function (data) {
        var doc = data.doc; // Internal jspdf instance
        doc.setFontSize(20);
        doc.setTextColor(40);
        doc.setFontStyle('normal');
        doc.text("Table Title", data.settings.margin.left, 60);
    }
}
```

Do note that you need `jspdf-autotable >=2.0.33`. For more information check out the autotable header and footer [demo](https://simonbengtsson.github.io/jsPDF-AutoTable/#header-footer) or [code](https://github.com/sjdedhia/jsPDF-AutoTable/blob/master/examples/examples.js#L143).

Comment: Thanks, but it says that 'doc' is not defined and I have no idea how and where I can define it through the plugin

Comment: My bad! I will update `jspdf-autotable` with a fix and I'll get back to you in a few minutes.

Comment: Nice, thank you ! I'll keep waiting, take your time :)

Comment: Done! Make sure you update `jspdf-autotable` to version >=2.0.33 and update your code according to above.

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thank you again, great job.